# Spring Transactional and CGLIB Proxy

Tags: java, spring, transactions, aop, cglib

I am attempting to couch my data source updates in a transaction within the Spring 3.0.7 container. My DAO class does not implement an interface and acts as a concrete class which is `@Autowired` by another bean (`@Component`). Here's the layout:

```
@Component
public class MyService {

  @Autowired
  MyDAO myDAO;

  public void myService(MyObj obj) {
    myDAO.updateObj(obj)
  }
}

@Component
public class MyDAO {
  // The data source bean is injected through a setter method
  // and used by updateObj()

  @Transactional
  public void updateObj(MyObj obj) {

     // multiple updates hence the need for transaction
  }
}
```

My application context has the transaction setup as following (this is a test unit bean config as I am invoking MyService/MyDAO through junit/Spring test case):

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="mypkg" />

    <bean id="updateDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
       <!-- properties for the data source -->
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="updateTxManager" />

    <bean id="updateTxManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="updateDataSource" ref="updateDataSource"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I am using Ant to perform my build. However, it seems like that I need to include CGLIB since `MyDAO` is not implementing an interface in order for Spring to create a proxy class.

Given that I am running Spring container version 3.0.7, along side spring-aop 3.0.7, spring-asm 3.0.0, aopalliance 1.0, I added cglib-nodep 3.0 jar file to my lib path. However, upon executing my test cases, I am getting the following exception:

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/asm/util/TraceClassVisitor
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.cglib.asm.util.TraceClassVisitor
```

Full stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyDAO' defined in file [C:\Users\.....\dao\MyDAO.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/asm/util/TraceClassVisitor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/asm/util/TraceClassVisitor
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.toByteArray(DebuggingClassWriter.java:73)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:26)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:144)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:116)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.createEnhancer(Cglib2AopProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:170)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:112)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:476)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:406)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.cglib.asm.util.TraceClassVisitor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 53 more
```

**Question**

Do you think the issue could be that the container/lib versions are in conflict? Do I need another lib that I am missing?

## Update

I had to create the project with `Mavon` and pull the dependencies to see which one it uses. It turns out what works is `cglib-nodep-2.2.2`, `asm-3.3.1`, `spring-aop-3.0.7`, `spring-asm-3.0.7`, and `aopalliance-1.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cglib` requires `asm` under the hood but `cglib-nodep` shades it so it should work. However, Spring is using cglib2 and not 3. Update your version to `cglib-nodep` 2.2.

Note also that as from the Spring Framework 3.2, `cglib` and `asm` are shaded in the `spring-core` library which means you don't have to deal with this issue at all anymore. If you can't sort that dependency problem, that would probably be the easiest move.

Comment: I have tried every possible cglib version from 2.2 up to 3.1. Any version other than 3.0 would cause the bean config not to be able to create the `updateDataSource` in the first place. I might as well run `maven` to see what version it pulls with Spring 3.0.7.

Comment: It does not pull anything as this is an optional dependency. You have to add it yourself if you need such proxy. Spring 3.0.x uses `cglib-nodep` 2.2 (see for instance https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3.0.x/org.springframework.context/pom.xml)

Comment: You may want to upgrade to 3.2 by the way. It's probably a jar replacement in your case and you don't need cglib at all since it's shaded in that version (and onwards).

Comment: Upgrading to the new framework is not an option, unfortunately. I see that Spring 3.0.8 requires ASM 3.0 (my project contains ASM 3.3). I wonder if that could be an issue. I'll have to get back to this some time later today.

Comment: cglib-nodep does not require asm since it's bundled (shaded) with it. Check the cglib version that you are using.